# Using OpenH264 DLL in C# Project

Tags: c#, c++, h.264, openh264

I'm receiving an H264 stream over UDP. I'd like to decode the stream so I can send frames to OpenCV or whatever. I came across Cisco's open sourced H264 decoder here: https://github.com/cisco/openh264 
With a little effort I got the decoder solution to build in Visual Studio 2019 and tested it from the command line with a file I created from the raw UDP datagrams. It works.

Now I want to figure out how to use the decoder DLL (welsdec.dll) in a C# project. The last time I did anything serious with C++ in Windows was back in the DirectShow and Delphi 5 days, so I'm completely lost.

Nothing in the H264 project is explicitly exported with __declspec(dllexport). Is that normal? Adding the DLL as a project reference to the C# project doesn't work ("the reference is invalid or unsupported").

I'm guessing the DLL is unmanaged. Can I consume that directly in C#? Am I going to have to rewrite the DLL as, or maybe or wrap it, in a C++ CX library to get this working?

Comment: https://github.com/secile/OpenH264Lib.NET

Comment: That project is perfect. Even if I don't use it directly, it's a great reference for how to setup the decoder. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consume an unmanaged DLL in C# explicitly using [PInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-call-native-dlls-from-managed-code-using-pinvoke?view=vs-2019).

You can also write an [intermediary DLL in C++/CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019) to ease the invocations between your managed C# application and the native DLL. This is the approach taken by [secile/OpenH264Lib.NET](https://github.com/secile/OpenH264Lib.NET) per [stuartd's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43846/stuartd) comment.

It looks like the H264 project uses [module definition files (.def)](https://github.com/cisco/openh264/blob/master/openh264.def) in lieu of decorating exports with `declspec`. You should still be able to access these publicly exported functions using the above methods.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me at the module definition files. That confirms what I found using dependency walker: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

So it should be as simple as getting the signature correct in a DllImport attribute.