# How could you use Q# within Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quantum-computing, q#

I was wondering how one would go about using Q# within Unity. I want to endow agents within a Unity simulation with quantum-like behavior, and I was wondering whether it was possible.

I've seen reference to adding a managed .dll in \Assets\Plugins and adding "`using yourLibraryNameSpace`;" at the top of scripts, but I'm not exactly sure whether/how that would work with the [Microsoft Quantum Development Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumLibraries). I've attached some potentially related posts below for reference. Any information would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much.

- [NuGet packages in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53447595/nuget-packages-in-unity;)
- [Unity C# how to load a managed DLL properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347537/unity-c-sharp-how-to-load-a-managed-dll-properly)

Comment: My guess at the easiest way would probably be to download the repository, build it into a DLL, and then load the DLL into Unity using the information from that second linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Someone pinged me about this on Twitter, so I figured I'd put out the quick-and-dirty prototype I put together last year: https://github.com/amirebrahimi/qsharp-unity